# jQuery Cycle plugin is choppy with larger images

Tags: jquery, html, css, cycle, jquery-cycle

My slideshow is choppy (looks like the fps is slow) when my images are a larger size, 1000 x 560 px. I resized the images to 200 x 200 as a test and the fade was smooth. Any ideas?

Comment: Animating big images will hit hard if your computer isn't up to par, don't expect desktop like performance in browsers, especially with IE6 still out there.

Comment: I'm not talking about speed because of transfers, but speeds because of the actual browser. You may have a smooth javascript animation in Chrome, but IE6 could stutter to a breakable amount, even on the same PC.

Comment: You're completely missing the point.

Comment: I get the point, what I dont get is why you're talking about IE6, when it's a completely deprecated browser with no support anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, the solution was to restart my mac! Odd...

Answer (score 1):

I think for larger images you're going to get some choppiness, especially when using jQuery animate.

Look at the difference between these two demos (use the left & right buttons):

- [Wide image scroll with jQuery animate](http://jsfiddle.net/MvRdD/)
- [Wide image scroll using scrollLeft](http://jsfiddle.net/MvRdD/1/)

So, I guess I'm saying try optimizing your code.